# Xamarin iOS: Does the iOS Timer continue at the same spot after going from background back to foreground

Tags: ios, xamarin, timer, nstimer

I have a timer in the FinishLaunching event inside the AppDelegate which was set to execute every 30 minutes.
If I move the application to the background or even suspended by device, I understand that the Timer will stop, but what happen if it goes back to foreground. Will the Timer continue from where it got stopped.

E.g. After 10 mins from Application start, I switched to application till it got background/suspended. 10 minutes later, I switch it back. Will the timer fires after 10 minutes or started all over again (30mins).

```
   downloadTimer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(30, DownloadEntityFromServer);

    NSRunLoop.Current.AddTimer(downloadTimer, NSRunLoopMode.Default);
```

Answer (score 0):

The timer will not be stopped if the application is suspended. It will keep on firing. 
There is no way to pause and resume the timer. Instead please refer the below workaround to pause and resume the timer.

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        NSTimer downloadTimer;
        DateTime date;
        TimeSpan RemainingMinutes;
        bool isBackground;
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            downloadTimer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(new TimeSpan(0,30,0), DownloadEntityFromServer);
            NSRunLoop.Current.AddTimer(downloadTimer, NSRunLoopMode.Default);
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }


        public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            RemainingMinutes = (DateTime.Now - date);
            isBackground = true;
            base.DidEnterBackground(uiApplication);
        }

        public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            isBackground = false;
            CreateTemporaryTimer();
            base.WillEnterForeground(uiApplication);
        }

        void CreateTemporaryTimer()
        {
           NSTimer tempTimer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(new TimeSpan(0,30-RemainingMinutes.Minutes,0), TemporaryTimerTicks);

        }

        void TemporaryTimerTicks(NSTimer obj)
        {
            downloadTimer.Invalidate();
            downloadTimer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(new TimeSpan(0,30,0), DownloadEntityFromServer);
        }

        void DownloadEntityFromServer(NSTimer obj)
        {
            date = DateTime.Now;
            if (!isBackground)
            {
              // Write your stuff
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What if not set, what would happen with the timer.

Comment: @LittleFunny I have modified the content. Can you try this? In this code, when the app is suspended at 10 mins and app is resumed the event will be triggered at 20 mins not 30 mins.

Comment: I think the Temporary Timer Tick method should called the DownloadEntityFromServer then call the NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer .